# CSS not changing depending on value jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to manipulate css using jquery my variable displays in console log, but the variable does not edit the css. Why is this? I have an input field where I would like the value to change the speed of the animation to the value entered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function(){
    var val = this.value;
        if (this.value > "0") {
            $(".orb").addClass("rotating");
            $(".rotating").css("animation","rotating'"+val+"'s linear infinite;")
        }
        else {
            $(".orb").removeClass("rotating");
        }
        console.log(val);
    });
});

.rotating {
   animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: What do you your code to do, exactly?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have added more information in my question

Comment: @beertwenty see my answer

Comment: Can you add your [mcve] code, we're missing the animation keyframes and the HTML you're working with.

Comment: check this row:
` $(".rotating").css("animation","rotating'"+val+"'s linear infinite;")`
there's more than one typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos, especially in this line:

```
$(".rotating").css("animation","rotating'"+val+"'s linear infinite;")
```

should be `$('.rotating').css("animation","rotating "+val+"s linear infinite");`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
            if (val > 0) {
                $(".orb").addClass("rotating");
                $('.rotating').css("animation","rotating "+val+"s linear infinite");
            }
            else {
                $(".orb").removeClass("rotating");
            }
            console.log(val);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this works exactly how I described. I was hoping for the object to increase in speed the higher the value. Which maths would I have to do to achieve this, as at the moment the hight the value the slower the animation?

Comment: Exactly. That's T seconds of the animation duration. You can use ms (milliseconds) instead of 's' (seconds) or you can divide the input value by 1000 to get smaller values in milliseconds. Whatever suits you best.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my question. I was wondering if i could make it so the higher the value the faster the rotation,, so if there was any maths i could do that would do the opposite, make higher numbers less seconds and lower numbers more?

Comment: You know that's another question, since the main question was 'I have an input field where I would like the value to change the speed of the animation to the value entered'. However 'you can divide the input value by 1000' or play around with it just like (1/myinputvalue*1000), etc etc. Get creative: math is fun.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it carefully like this

You may have

1. made a silly error
2. intermixed value string and number
3. improperly escape quotes

I see you have compared your value to '0' which is string and has other numeric equivalent 
Instead try like this ->

if (Number(inputfield.value)>0) {...code}

Please post full html code so i can debug it

```js
function f() {
  var a=$(`#p`).val();
  console.log(a);
  $(`.r`).css(`animation`,`spin ${a}s infinite`)
}
```

```css
.r {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r">askjnhd</div>
<input id='p' />
<button onclick="f()">doit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trick the system when cancelling the animation and start it again

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (this.value > "0") {
      //$(".orb").addClass("rotating");
      var animation =  "rotating " + val + "s linear infinite";
      console.log(animation);
      $(".rotating").css("animation", "none");
      $(".rotating").css("animation", animation)
    } else {
      $(".orb").removeClass("rotating");
    }
    console.log(val);
  });
});
```

```css
.rotating {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div class="rotating"></div>
```